# Deferred (lazy) loading of background images?

Tags: javascript, background-image, lazy-loading

I'm using a simple script to cause a deferred loading of all images on a page; the path for the image sources is contained in a `data-src` attribute and then put into the actual `src`attribute of the `img` tag(s). Pretty much how most (?) implementations of the lazy loading method work.

Here's the script:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]'), function(img) {
  img.setAttribute('src', img.getAttribute('data-src'));
  img.onload = function() {
    img.removeAttribute('data-src');
  };
});
```

I would like to use the same script for deferred loading of background images as well. How do I have to change it so that the `data-src` attribute ends up in the `url`-value of a `div`'s `background-image`-property?

I tried the following with no results, because the script doesn't recognise `background-image` as a property:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div[data-src]'), function(div) {
  div.setAttribute('background-image', div.getAttribute('data-src'));
  div.onload = function() {
    div.removeAttribute('data-src');
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem may be with the background image as an attribute. Have you tried setting the style with the background image?

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div[data-src]'), function(div) {
  div.setAttribute("style","background-image: url(" + div.getAttribute('data-src') + ");");
  div.onload = function() {
    div.removeAttribute('data-src');
  };
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. Could you also tell me how to set additional style properties alongside the background-image, like background-size?

Comment: You could add additional CSS to the string like so. I added the color red to it. 

div.setAttribute("style","background-image: url(" + div.getAttribute('data-src') + "); color: red;");

Answer (score 0):

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div[data-src]'), function(div) {
  div.style.backgroundImage="url('" + div.getAttribute('data-src') + "')";
  div.onload = function() {
    div.removeAttribute('data-src');
  };
});
```

Try this